# Wordpress plugin to animate from page to page in navigation

Tags: wordpress, animation, plugins, jquery-animate

I am looking for a wordpress plugin that will animate the page to move horizontally off the page after clicking on the main navigation and bring the other page into view. Similar to http://www.maximintegrated.com/

Does anyone know of a plugin that does this? Or how to do it?

Comment: call data of all the pages to the homepage and use jquery to slide the content..
http://www.kyrielles.net/sliderkit/demos/content-sliders.html

Comment: thanks for your quick reply. how do you call all pages to one page?